# How to enable less in Rails 3.2 using Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, asset-pipeline, twitter-bootstrap, less, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I decided to use the [twitter-bootstrap-rails gem](https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails) and then ran these generators:

```
rails g bootstrap:install 
rails g bootstrap:layout application fluid
rails g bootstrap:themed products
```

and it installed some files as expected, but when I access to my application it has the links and button with the Twitter style but the nav the content and the sidebar are all not fixed.

It seems that `bootstrap.css.less` is not being open I've tried installing the following:

- less
- less-rails
- less-rails-bootstrap

but nothing happens. Is there any extra configuration that I have to do?

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Less in a Rails 3.2 application with Edge twitter-bootstrap-rails
in my Gemfile:

```
gem 'twitter-bootstrap-rails', :git => 'http://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails.git'
```

You might be able to get this to work putting it under the 'assets' group, but for my needs, I had to include it for the whole application.

After that, follow the instructions at https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails and see how you go.

My installation seems to differ from yours, as my bootstrap less file is app/assets/stylesheets/bootstrap_and_overrides.css.less

If this is true for you, you should rename any include/imports from 'bootstrap' to 'bootstrap_and_overrides'

The only other thing I can think of, is that Twitter Bootstrap requires JQuery 1.7.

Hope this helps,